# GetElementByID failing in IE, works in Chrome and FF

Tags: javascript, filepicker.io

I've looked and looked, but can't find solution to this exact issue.  I have a form that returns a couple of values into the variables **_ and _**.  I'm using those values to update other form values with the 'setfilenameinbox' function.  This works fine in both Chrome and Firefox, but the value doesn't get updated in all versions of IE that I've tested with (both 7 & 8).

Would very much appreciate knowing why code won't work in IE.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   function setfilenameinbox(uploadname, url){
       document.getElementById("textboxFileName").value = uploadname;
       document.getElementById("FPFileURL").value = url;
   }

   function openFilePicker(){

      filepicker.setKey('***edited out for help***');

      filepicker.pick({
          extensions: ['.pdf', '.jpg'],
          container: 'window',
          services:['COMPUTER', 'DROPBOX', 'GOOGLE_DRIVE'],
            },
            function(FPFile){
                console.log(JSON.stringify(FPFile));

                //upload complete
                setfilenameinbox(FPFile.filename, FPFile.url);
                },
            function(FPError){
                console.log(FPError.toString());
                }
        );
    } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think IE7 and 8 have no `console` object (unless some library or plugin supplied it with one). The `console.log` should break your code in < IE8. I suggest you remove `console` commands in production.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll see if I can re-write functions without using 'console.log' and see what happens.